# Node.js project: can't setup bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I try to setup a nodejs project called "docdoku-web-front" and i have dependencies problems on bower.
When i try to install my project with the command: `npm run dev`, i have this errors:

```
Please note that,
datatables#1.9.4 depends on jquery#~1.8.0 which resolved to jquery#1.8.3
docdokuplm depends on jquery#1.9.1 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
bootstrap-switch#1.7.0 depends on jquery#~1.9.0 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
jqueryui#1.9.2 depends on jquery#>= 1.8 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
selectize#0.12.6 depends on jquery#>=1.7.0 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
bootstrap-datepicker#1.4.1 depends on jquery#>=1.7.1 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
bootstrap#3.4.1 depends on jquery#1.9.1 - 3 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
bootstrap#2.3.2 depends on jquery#>=1.8.0 <2.1.0 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
jQuery-QueryBuilder#2.0.1 depends on jquery#>= 1.9.0 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
jquery-extendext#0.1.2 depends on jquery#>=1.9.1 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
Resort to using jquery#1.9.1 which resolved to jquery#1.9.1
Code incompatibilities may occur.

Please note that,
    docdokuplm depends on bootstrap#~2.3.2 which resolved to bootstrap#2.3.2
    bootstrap-datepicker#1.4.1 depends on bootstrap#>=2.0.4 <4.0 which resolved to bootstrap#3.4.1
    jQuery-QueryBuilder#2.0.1 depends on bootstrap#^3.1.0 which resolved to bootstrap#3.4.1
Resort to using bootstrap#~2.3.2 which resolved to bootstrap#2.3.2
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

After investigating, i believe i must change versions on bower.json but i don't know how.

Here is my bower.json

```
    {
  "name": "docdokuplm",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "backbone": "~1.0.0",
    "bootbox": "~3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "~2.3.2",
    "bootstrap-combobox": "~1.1.6",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "~1.4.1",
    "bootstrap-switch": "#1.7.0",
    "buzz": "~1.1.4",
    "dat.gui": "*",
    "datatables": "1.9.4",
    "date.format": "~1.2.3",
    "fontawesome": "~4.7.0",
    "jquery": "#1.9.1",
    "jquery-maskedinput": "~1.3.1",
    "jQuery-QueryBuilder": "~2.0.1",
    "jqueryui": "1.9.2",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "modernizr": "~2.7.1",
    "moment": "~2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.5.11",
    "mustache": "~0.8.2",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.10",
    "requirejs-i18n": "~2.0.4",
    "requirejs-text": "~2.0.10",
    "selectize": "~0.12.0",
    "threejs": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/r90/build/three.min.js",
    "tweenjs": "~16.6.0",
    "underscore": "~1.4.2",
    "unorm": "1.3.3",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "bootstrap": "~2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Do you have ideas how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, i find the solution. My user session have not enough permissions, when i try to install bower manually, i have not permissions on /usr/bin/bower. And i have the same problem with the grunt server. I think i must remove my session and restart setup.